# Is it possible to use Rebus with Azure Functions?

Tags: azure-functions, rebus, rebus-azureservicebus

I am new to Rebus and was looking for some documentation about triggering azure functions using Rebus with Azure Service Bus provider.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

Rebus does not have any kind of integration with Azure Functions, but you're free to let your Azure Functions be triggered by messages sent from Rebus, and you can easily use Rebus' one-way client mode to send messages from Azure Functions:

```cs
using var bus = Configure
    .With(new BuiltinHandlerActivator())
    .Transport(t => t.UseAzureServiceBusAsOneWayClient(conn))
    .Routing(r => r.TypeBased().Map<MyMessage>("destination-queue"))
    .Start();

await bus.Send(new MyMessage());
```

Comment: So you suggest sending a message using Rebus and let the azure function be triggered directly by Azure Service Bus, right?

Comment: Can you use Rebus sagas along with Azure Service Bus?

Comment: @Enrico yes :) with Rebus you can use pretty much any combination of saga persister (i.e. database for saving saga data) and transport (i.e. queueing system) as you like.